# Using Command Prompt to create random strings as varables

Tags: variables, batch-file

I need a way to generate random variables for folder names, and them call on them with %%. Cheers in advance people

Answer (score 1):

openssl can generate random values for you.

`openssl rand -hex 32 | less`

Answer (score 0):

There is a special environmental `%random%` which will contain a number between 1 and 32,767.

so

```
md c:\folder%random%
```

unlike other variables it is always a different number even if used like this to increase the randomness range.

```
md c:\folder%random%%random%
```

Also `%date%` and/or `%time%` can be used. You need to remove illegal characters from these strings.

For time (removes `:`)

```
set tmptime=%time%
set  rndtime=%tmptime::=%
```

and for date (removes `/`)

```
set tmpdate=%date%
set  rnddate=%tmpdate:/=%
```